# Cannot load jupyter notebook tree page

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I uninstalled/reinstalled anaconda distribution - Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe - on windows 10. When I launch jupyter notebook from command prompt, I get in the browser at address http://localhost:8888/tree a blank page [image: blank initial page]. Clearing browser cache does not work, start in private mode does not work, chrome/opera/Edge do not load anything. The console does not show any error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate to localhost:8888/

Perhaps you are not authenticated. If it does not work please check jupyter logs (or post it here).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that the current notebook package version is broken. Downgrading to version 5.7.2 fixed the problem. There are plenty of guys complaining on this.